# UseMethod("type") error; no applicable method for 'type" applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"

Tags: r, stringr

In a dataframe, I have a column that has numeric values and some mixed in character data for some rows. I want to remove all rows with the character data and keep those rows with a number value. The df I have is 6 million rows, so I simply made a small object to try to solve my issue and then implement at a larger scale.

Here is what I did:

```
a <- c("fruit", "love", 53)

b <- str_replace_all("^[:alpha:]", 0)
```

Reading answers to other UseMethod errors on here (about factors), I tried to change "a" to as.character(a) and attempt "b" again. But, I get the same error. I'm trying to simply make any alphabetic value into the number zero and I'm fairly new at all this.

Comment: What if you replace the `0` with `"0"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues here, even in these two lines of code.  First, `a` is a character vector, because its first element is a character.  This means that your numeric `53` is coerced into a character.

```
> print(a)
[1] "fruit" "love"  "53"
```

You've got the wrong syntax for `str_replace_all`.  See the documentation for how to use it correctly.  But that's not what you want here, because you want numerics.

The first thing you need to do is convert `a` to a numeric.  A crude way of doing this is simply

```
>b <- as.numeric(a)
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion b
> b
[1] NA NA 53
```

And then subset to include only the numeric values in `b`:

```
> b <- b[!is.na(b)]
> b
[1] 53
```

But whether that's what you want to do with a 6 million row dataframe is another matter.  Please think about exactly what you would like to do, supply us with better test data, and ask your question again.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a more efficient way of doing this on a large data frame (e.g. something column-wise, instead of row-wise), but to answer your specific question about each row `a`:

```
as.numeric(stringr::str_replace_all(a, "[a-z]+", "0"))
```

Note that the replacing value must be a character (the last argument in the function call, `"0"`). (You can look up the documentation from your R-console by: `?stringr::str_replace_all`)